# Call Backbone view method from inside google chrome console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools, backbone-views

I'd like to have access to my Backbone View object from inside the console. So for example lets say I have

```
mySlider = new SliderView( el: $('.slider')[0] )
```

and that SliderView has a `goTo(idx)` method. How can I do this inside the console:

```
mySlider.goTo(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the view to the global scope by attaching it to the `window` object:

```
window.mySlider = new SliderView( el: $('.slider')[0] );
```

Now you can access it in the Chrome console:

```
mySlider.goTo(1);
```